# Fixing a NoClassDefFoundError on Custom Classloader

Tags: java

```
public class JarByteClassloader extends ClassLoader {
  public JarInputStream jis;
  public JarByteClassloader(JarInputStream jarInputStream) throws IOException {
    super(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    this.jis = jarInputStream;
  }
}
```

Which is used in here:

```
public void executeMainClass(CustomCodeRequest request) {
    String classToLoad = null;
    String methodName = request.getMethodName();
    final ClassLoader originalClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    try{
      Pair<String,JarInputStream> pair = extractMainClassManifest(jar);
      classToLoad = pair.getFirst();
      JarByteClassloader loader = new JarByteClassloader(pair.getSecond());
      Class c = loader.loadClass(classToLoad);
      Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(loader);
      JarEntryObject jarEntry = (JarEntryObject) c.newInstance();
      List<JarCodeMethod> methods = jarEntry.methods();
      for (JarCodeMethod cc : methods) {
        // This code throws NoClassDefFoundError
        String ccMethodName = cc.getMethodName();
        if (methodName.equals(ccMethodName)) {

        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
      Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(originalClassLoader);
    }
  }
```

Throws:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/apex/backends/methods/ProcessBranch
    at com.apex.backends.MyJarEntryObject.methods(MyJarEntryObject.java:22)
```

What could be the root cause of the `NoClassDefFoundError`? And how can it be fixed?

Where the jar is is like

> public class MyJarEntryObject extends JarEntryObject{     @Override
>     public List methods() {       List
>   methods = new LinkedList();         methods.add(new
>   ProcessMethod());         return methods;     } }

Comment: com/apex/backends/methods/ProcessBranch is not present in the class loader that execute the imported class . if its a field of the main class or used by the main class the class loader it run have not this class